# static var in member function

Tags: apache-flex, function, variables, static

I would like to know, in Flex 4.5.1, if there is a way to create a static variable in a member function, something like bellow:

```
public function myFunction():void {
    static test:Object = null;
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to define static variables in a class, but you can assign a value later in your function.

```
public class MyClass {

    private static var test:Object;

    public function myFunction():void {
        test = new Object();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare class members inside functions but you can only initialize them there. Why not declare it outside function?

```
private static var test:Object;

public function myFunction():void {
    test = null;
}
```

Comment: In fact, I'm using a static variable only in one member function, so to do not pollute my source code, I would have liked to create it directly in the member function (I think it's possible in other language, isn't it?)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? As a side note creating static variables are not available in any languages with the same conceptions like Java. And if you want to have bad architecture you can define your class as dynamic and assign inexistent static property without declaration.